# How can I map between two enums using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a public facing interface that I'm trying to map two different enumerations to each other.  I tried to use the following code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contract_1_1_0.ValidationResultType, Common.ValidationResultType>();
```

When that didn't work, I tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contract_1_1_0.ValidationResultType, Common.ValidationResultType>().ConvertUsing(x => (Common.ValidationResultType)((int)x));
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.  Is there anyway to get automapper to handle this scenario?

Comment: Did you receive an error?  What didn't work?

Comment: I received an "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping." error.

Comment: Can you post your enums?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You don't need to do CreateMap for enum types. Just get rid of the CreateMap call and it should work, as long as the names and/or values match up between enum types.

Comment: When following this practice, will it adapt using enum value or member name ?

Comment: What if the names and values don't match?

Comment: Then you'd need to create a custom type converter.

Comment: @JimmyBogard : empList.Project().To<destination.Employee>().  If source Employee and destination Employee contain Enum. Then It won't work. It gives exception  of Unable map Enum to Int 32

Comment: "You don't need to do X using Y" is not an answer to "How do I do X using Y". Of course, it never hurts to ask if Y is really necessary--often times it isn't.

Comment: @threed the question was "how do I map two enums using AutoMapper". My answer is the answer. The rest of the question started down the wrong road about things the OP tried. My answer put them on the right path.

Comment: Am I missing something? I'm getting an error "Unable to create a map expression from (enum type) to (enum type)" but both types have the same number of values and names for each.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, oddly enough it seems to work for one enum and not another. The only difference I can see is the one that does not work has disjoint values (i.e. it has specified values 1, 2, 4, 9 and not 1, 2, 3, 4).

Comment: Oh wow, sorry for the comment deluge but apparently the error was being caused by something else, akin to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/280 . After creating the enum map, I got the "Argument types do not match", found the problem which entailed making said enum property nullable. Then I just found I could actually remove the custom enum mapping. Very odd, but in case someone finds the same thing hopefully this comment will help.

Comment: Can someone give an example of what this answer is trying to portray?

Answer (score 87):

Alternatively to writing custom converters, just use ConvertUsing()

```c#
Mapper.CreateMap<EnumSrc, EnumDst>().ConvertUsing((value, destination) => 
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case EnumSrc.Option1:
            return EnumDst.Choice1;
        case EnumSrc.Option2:
            return EnumDst.Choice2;
        case EnumSrc.Option3:
            return EnumDst.Choice3;
        default:
            return EnumDst.None;
    }
});
```

Comment: I was using `ConstructUsing` and it was somehow returning the wrong enum even though my code was a giant switch statement returning the right enum. Using `ConvertUsing` fixed the problem.

Comment: If I try this, I get an `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree` error... The approach is great though.

Comment: You have to match the expression signature, in this case the example above is missing the `destination` argument. Replacing `value =>` with `(value, destination) =>` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 19):

My Automapper works this way:

**If I create a map:**
Automapper will match enums by value, even if name match perfectly.

**If I do not create a map:**
Automapper will match enums by name.

Answer (score 7):

The Simplest Way I found that work for me is as below:

My Enum is a nested in another class so I Use ForMember method and MapFrom as below:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ProblematicCustomer, ProblematicCustomerViewModel>()                
            .ForMember(m=> m.ProblemType, opt=> opt.MapFrom(x=> (ProblemTypeViewModel)(int)x.ProblemType))
            .ForMember(m=> m.JudgmentType, opt=> opt.MapFrom(x=> (JudgmentTypeViewModel)(int)x.JudgmentType));
```

The ProblemType and JudgmentType are Enums. And their related View Models are ProblemTypeViewModel and JudgmentTypeViewModel with same members as their related Models.

Although I don't test, But I think below line should work for you:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contract_1_1_0.ValidationResultType, Common.ValidationResultType>()
           .ForMember(m=> m, opt => opt.MapFrom(x=> (Common.ValidationResultType)(int)x);
```

Hope it Help.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here didn't work for me.

You need to create a class that implements:

```
ITypeConvertor<SourceType ,DestinationType>
```

So as an example

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<EnumType1.VatLevel, EnumType2.VatRateLevel>()
       .ConvertUsing(new VatLevelConvertor());
```

And the class:

```
internal class VatLevelConvertor : ITypeConverter<EnumType1.VatLevel, EnumType2.VatRateLevel>
{
    public EnumType2.VatRateLevel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        EnumType1.VatLevel value = (EnumType1.VatLevel)context.SourceValue;
        switch (value)
        {
            case EnumType1.VatLevel.Standard:
                return EnumType2.VatRateLevel.Normal;
            case EnumType1.VatLevel.Reduced:
                return EnumType2.VatRateLevel.Lower;
            case EnumType1.VatLevel.SuperReduced:
                return EnumType2.VatRateLevel.Other;
            default:
                return EnumType2.VatRateLevel.Other;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possibility for making a conversion between two Enum types that both have different values, while still using AutoMapper.  In my case, I needed to use AutoMapper because the Enum types were properties on other entities being converted by AutoMapper; using AutoMapper for these entities was a requirement.

The first step is to setup the Mapper configuration like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EnumSrc, EnumDst>()
    .ConstructUsing(EnumConversion.FromSrcToDst);
```

Calling `.ConstructUsing(...)` allows us to pass in our own method for making the conversion. The method for conversion is pretty straight forward:

```
public class EnumConversion
{
    internal static EnumDst FromSrcToDst(ResolutionContext arg)
    {
        EnumSrc value = (EnumSrc)arg.SourceValue;
        switch(value)
        {
            case EnumSrc.Option1:
                return EnumDst.Choice1;
            case EnumSrc.Option2:
                return EnumDst.Choice2;
            case EnumSrc.Option3:
                return EnumDst.Choice3;
            default:
                return EnumDst.None;
        }
    }
}
```

We simply `switch` through  the values of the source Enum and return the appropriate destination Enum value arbitrarily. AutoMapper takes care of the rest.

Comment: I tried this implementation and it just mapped based on the integer value (AutoMapper 3.3.1). I will add my answer that worked below

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old but if some people like me pass by here...

From the [AutoMapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Enum-Mapping.html) there's now a [AutoMapper.Extensions.EnumMapping Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.EnumMapping) providing a simple way to do it.

Quote from the AutoMapper documentation:

```cs
public enum Source
{
    Default = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2
}

public enum Destination
{
    Default = 0,
    Second = 2
}

internal class YourProfile : Profile
{
    public YourProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ConvertUsingEnumMapping(opt => opt
                // optional: .MapByValue() or MapByName(), without configuration MapByValue is used
                .MapValue(Source.First, Destination.Default)
            )
            .ReverseMap(); // to support Destination to Source mapping, including custom mappings of ConvertUsingEnumMapping
    }
}
```

Comment: But other than `ReverseMap`, everything can be easily done with the base package, so that's rarely useful.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Sorry but searching on Google leads to either the documentation page I linked in my answer or this SO question. However in all answers above I don't see any straightforward ways to do it with the AutoMapper base package. Personally I don't like using the `ConvertUsing` method and writing a switch case inside. I find my way shorter and therefore clearer. Could you please provide your way to do it with the ** base package**? Thanks

Comment: As it says above, you get map by names by default (fallback to value) and if you create a map, by values. And then a `switch` expression is both cleaner and easier to understand than your code. With a package reference less.

Comment: Ok the point of my answer was actually to show how to map Enums with different property names. In my case I had 2 enums with same constant names EXCEPT ONE. In that case I couldn't use the default name mapping and writing a switch case would force me to manually map ALL constants even if they've the same name. With `ConvertUsingEnumMapping` I could specify a mapping only for the destination's constant name that differs from source one. I'll leave my answer as I think it could still benefit other people. More convenient than a switch case in my opinion

Comment: No, `Enum.TryParse` would cover the rest, just two branches. And the values match in your case, you don't even need that, it's just a cast. I guess a simple conditional works, you don't even need a `switch`.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a mapper for two Enums, that's it! Automapper will map by the either the matching value or index value of the Enum. (e.g. Draft -> Step1)

```
public enum SourceStatus
{
    Draft,
    Submitted,
    Deleted
}

public enum DestinationStatus
{
    Step1,
    Step2,
    Step3
}

public class SourceObj
{
    public SourceStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationObj
{
    public DestinationStatus Status { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Static APi style - this is obsolete now. From Version 5.0 onwards    this will be removed.
        SourceObj mySrcObj = new SourceObj();
        mySrcObj.Status = SourceStatus.Deleted;

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceStatus, DestinationStatus>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceObj, DestinationObj>();

        DestinationObj myDestObj = Mapper.Map<SourceObj, DestinationObj>(mySrcObj);

        //New way of doing it
        SourceObj mySrcObj2 = new SourceObj();
        mySrcObj2.Status = SourceStatus.Draft;

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceObj, DestinationObj>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var source = new SourceObj();
        var dest = mapper.Map<SourceObj, DestinationObj>(source);



    }
}
```

Comment: Enum mapping like this is very dangerous. You know what happens when  one type has numbers and the other does not have number? It gets REKT I dont know why but it just doesnt work anymore especially if we want to have a null default value.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to map between "equal" enums using Automapper, but unfortunately it didn't work. I suspect the problem is a difference in casing:

```
public enum Foo {
    val1,
    val2
}

public enum Bar {
    Val1,
    Val2
}
```

`Foo` is something auto-generated from an XSD, and the supplier sucks. Also there are thirty-something values and I didn't want to put a `switch` that large anywhere for something so silly.

The approach I took was to convert the source value to string and parse that as the destination value:

```
static Foo ConvertEnum(Bar source)
{
    Foo result;
    var parsed = Enum.TryParse(source.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(), true, out result);
    if(!parsed)
         // throw or return default value
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("source", source, "Unknown source value");
    return result;
}
```

Of course, this only works if your enums only have differences in casing. You could make it more elaborate by cleaning up the input string (e.g. remove underscores etc.) or by adding stuff to it as required.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old topic, but it's the main one I get when googling, so decided to show my findings.

I have source and destination enums. They don't fully match, but sometimes there might be an overlap of the value (the numeric one), but that match might not be correct. To illustrate, here are 2 enums:

```
enum EnumA {
  Item1 = 5,
  Item2 = 10,
  Item3 = 15
}

enum EnumB {
  I1 = 15,
  I2 = 10,
  I3 = 5
}
```

I wanted to have an explicit map between the two, so I have a switch case like this:

```
source switch {
  EnumA.Item1 => EnumB.I1,
  EnumA.Item2 => EnumB.I2,
  EnumA.Item3 => EnumB.I3,
  _ => throw new ArgumentException("")
}
```

So far, so good, this works as expected. The interesting part comes when I tried to hook it to AutoMapper.

I've defined a mapping like this

```
CreateMap<EnumA, EnumB>().ConvertUsing((src, dest) => src switch {
  EnumA.Item1 => EnumB.I1,
  EnumA.Item2 => EnumB.I2,
  EnumA.Item3 => EnumB.I3,
  _ => throw new ArgumentException("")
});
```

And then used it as a regular member map

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.PropA, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PropB))
```

With this code however, when there is a match of the number ids, I would get the wrong enum member.

The only way I could make it work was to defined a value converter

```
public class ItemConverter : IValueConverter<EnumA, EnumB>
{
  public CountryCode Convert(EnumA sourceMember, ResolutionContext context) => sourceMember switch
  {
    EnumA.Item1 => EnumB.I1,
    EnumA.Item2 => EnumB.I2,
    EnumA.Item3 => EnumB.I3,
    _ => throw new ArgumentException("")
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.PropA, opts => opts.ConvertUsing(new ItemConverter(), src => src.PropB))
```

Hope it helps someone like me in the future